# Locate para dois campos

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10

Como fazer uma pesquisa com `Locate` com dois ou mais campos simultaneamente?

- Quais as desvantagens de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOCATE - Declaração:

```
function Locate(const KeyFields: string; const KeyValues: Variant; Options: TLocateOptions): Boolean; virtual;
```

Esse método permite a busca exata de um registro, por campos que não façam parte do índice corrente da tabela representada pelo componente, e recebe como parâmetros:

- Uma string contendo os nomes dos campos pelos quais será feita a
  pesquisa (separados por ponto-e-vírgula).
- Uma string contendo os valores a serem pesquisados nos campos pelos
  quais será feita a pesquisa (separados por ponto-e-vírgula).
- Um conjunto de opções, que pode conter os seguintes elementos: LoCaseInsensitive - se esse elemento for incluído, letras maiúsculas e minúsculas serão tratadas indiferentemente; `LoPartialKey` – indica que a pesquisa será aproximada.

Esse é uma exemplo de como fazer o método `Locate` com dois campos que encontrei no [docwiki.embarcadero.com/Using_Locate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_Locate).

```
CustTable.IndexFieldNames := 'ID'; 
if CustTable.Locate('ID1';'ID1', VarArrayOf([´String1´,´String2´]), [])then
  ShowMessage ('O cliente com ID = String1 e ID = String2 encontrado')
else 
  ShowMessage ('O cliente não encontrado') ;
```

No [docwiki.embarcadero.com](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.Locate) tem toda a descrição do método e também encontrei outro método que pesquisa com dos campos que é o [Extended Locating](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.LocateEx) deem uma olhada  o método `LocateEx` aceita valores de campo ou expressões.

- **Valor de Campo**:

  ```
  if not CustTable.LocateEx('COMPANY', 'AMCO', [lxoCaseInsensitive]) then
    ShowMessage('The customer from AMCO company is not found')
  else
    ShowMessage('Order is not found');
  ```
- **Expressão**:

  ```
  if FDQuery1.LocateEx('Price >= 1000 and Price <= 2000', []) then
    ShowMessage('Order is found')
  else
    ShowMessage('Order is not found');
  ```

Answer (score 2):

O `Locate` que estou acostumado a fazer é neste formato:

```
DataSetX.Locate('CODIGO;DATAVENCTO;COD_PRODUTO',VarArrayOf([QOperacoesCODIGO.AsInteger
                                                           ,QOperacoesDATAVENCIMENTO.AsDateTime
                                                           ,QOperacoesPRODUTO.AsInteger]), [])
```

A desvantagem do `Locate` existe somente quando você possui um `DataSet` que não foi carregado com `FetchAll`, pois, ao executa-lo pode ser necessário que o DataSet recarregue todos os dados da Tabela, aumentando o consumo de memória.

Uma boa alternativa seria usar uma `ClientDataSet` que possua propriedade de compactação de dados, dessa forma você carregaria esta client com os dados do dataset e o destruiria, restando apenas a Client com os dados prontos para pesquisa.

Em uma Client usaria o `FindKey` o funcionamento é o mesmo, porem, muito mais rápido.

```
ClientDataSetX.FindKey([QOperacoesCODIGO.AsInteger
                        ,QOperacoesDATAVENCIMENTO.AsDateTime
                        ,QOperacoesPRODUTO.AsInteger])
```

Vale lembrar que para isto precisa definir um Índice para a Client funcionar corretamente, no caso do exemplo citado o Índice seria pelos campos **CODIGO, DATAVENCIMENTO E PRODUTO**.

Comment: Observar que no Locate não deve-se separa os campos String por ','. A constante `KeyFields` é apenas uma string.

Comment: Ok. Bem posto @Júnior Moreira.